# Computation of the Frenet-Serret trihedron in $\Bbb L^3$ (Lorentz-Minkowski space)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, semi-riemannian-geometry

Consider $\Bbb L^3 = (\Bbb R^3, \langle , \rangle)$, with the convention $$\langle (x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2)\rangle = x_1x_2+y_1y_2 - z_1z_2$$
and $\| v \| = \sqrt{|\langle v, v \rangle|}$.

Let $\alpha: I \subset \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb L^3$ be a spacelike curve, parametrized by arc-length, and $\mathbf{T}(s) := \alpha '(s)$ be the tangent vector to $\alpha$ at $s$. Suppose $\mathbf{T}'(s)$ is lightlike for all $s$. Then we define the normal vector $\mathbf{N}(s) := \mathbf{T}'(s)$, and the binormal vector $\mathbf{B}(s)$ as the unique lightlike vector orthogonal to $\mathbf{T}(s)$ such that $\langle \mathbf{N}(s), \mathbf{B}(s) \rangle = 1$. We do not define the curvature in this case. I have no problem accepting these definitions, and I can even prove the Frenet-Serret equations: $$\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{T}' \\ \mathbf{N}' \\ \mathbf{B}' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \tau & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & -\tau \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{T} \\ \mathbf{N} \\ \mathbf{B} \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\tau$ will be the torsion of the curve.

However, I am having some trouble understanding how to compute the binormal vector in practical cases. Surely I could write $\alpha(s) = (x(s), y(s), z(s))$, and $\mathbf{B}(s) = (b_1(s), b_2(s), b_3(s))$, and try to solve the system $$\left\{\begin{array}{c} b_1(s)~x'(s) + b_2(s)~y'(s) - b_3(s)~z'(s) = 0 \\ b_1(s)~x''(s) + b_2(s)~y''(s) - b_3(s)~z''(s) = 1 \\ (b_1(s))^2 + (b_2(s))^2 - (b_3(s))^2 = 0 \end{array} \right.$$

I think that in general, it's very hard to solve this. Can someone give some insight about this, or make an example?

I have the same problem if $\alpha$ is lightlike and pseudo-parametrized by arc-length, but if I can understand this case, I can probably manage the other one by myself. There shouldn't be much difference. Thank you!

(If it happens to help, I'm using [this text](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3351.pdf))

Comment: Is the inner product of $N$ and $B$ really 1? I am currently under the impression that the $T,N,B$ system of coordinates is an orthonormal set that moves along the curve $\alpha$. If we know $T$ and we can then calculate $N$ as a derivative and then $B$ as $T\times N$?

Comment: Yes, $\langle \mathbf{N}, \mathbf{B} \rangle = 1$ *by definition*. I also spent a long time trying to accept this definition, but if it weren't like this, the vectors would be linearly dependent and we couldn't solve for all the coefficients of the combinations, to put in the matrix there. Also, notice that since we have lightlike vectors in the play, the orthonormal basis will not exist. These definitions are the best way to copy the usual frame that was distorted in the space-time. I know it has almost no intuition behing them, but unfortunately it is this way.